# sort an arrayList

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I have a Array list I want to sort it alphabetically would you please help me on this implementation

Thanks in advance!

```
 public ArrayList<ListData> getList(String itemsKey) {
    if (itemsKey.equalsIgnoreCase(“names”)) {


        return nameList;

    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to return nameList sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a custom `Comparator` to sort this collection. It's hard to write the exact code without knowing your `ListItem` and `NameDefinition` classes, but it would be something like this (supposing `NameDefinition` has a `name` field -- if not, adjust accordingly):

```
Collections.sort(nameList, new Comparator<ListData.ListItem>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(ListItem lhs, ListItem rhs)
    {
        return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(lhs.nameDefinition.name, rhs.nameDefinition.name);
    }
});
```

Comment: @JonHudson Before your return statement. You could create a private class inside your class for the comparator to clean the code.

Comment: @TyMarc You're right about the private class, of course. I just wanted to provide the most compact snippet possible :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
Collections.sort(nameList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

It will sort your strings alphabetically.

Comment: It said Collections cannot be applied